# Unsure if this is a good tag wiki edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I was served up [this suggested tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8946360) for [webdatagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdatagrid).  The edit has:

> WebDataGrid™ is built on top of the Infragistics ASP.NET AJAX framework. It is an efficient and scalable grid control, with native AJAX capabilities.

Which is an exact copy from [this site](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/ASPNET/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/WebDataGrid_About_WebDataGrid.html):

> WebDataGrid™ is built on top of the Infragistics ASP.NET AJAX framework. It is an efficient and scalable grid control, with native AJAX capabilities.

There is a reject reason for:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance

But I am unsure if this applies in this case.  What should one do in a case like this?  Should we treat `significant amount` as a percentage of the information that is in the tag wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not just a verbatim copy of another site, but a verbatim copy of the sales pitch.
I'd at least remove the "efficient" part, and perhaps the "and scalable" as well.

That leaves you with:

> WebDataGrid™ is built on top of the Infragistics ASP.NET AJAX framework. It is a grid control, with native AJAX capabilities.

I'd personally re-order the sentences a bit:

> WebDataGrid™ is a grid control with native AJAX capabilities. It is built on top of the Infragistics ASP.NET AJAX framework.

Normally, I'd want to add the source as well; however, the link you gave is to the tag wiki excerpt, which should be kept short. Note that the editor actually added attribution in the actual tag wiki. (And, sadly, nothing other than the attribution... even a little explanation would have made it so much better).

On the whole, I don't think this was a very good edit suggestion.
My choice would be to either "Improve" or "Reject & Edit" - assuming one can spare the time to turn this suggestion into a proper edit.
It's good that there's a tag wiki and an excerpt, but a tag wiki should be neutral and this edit suggestion wasn't.